# Very small FPS ranges - camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

When I call `cameraCharacteristics.get(CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES)` on Samsung Galaxy S9 - it returns an array with ranges containing values `[15, 15], [24, 24], [7, 30], [15, 30], [30, 30]`. I am quite sure that it supports much bigger FPS, or it isn't?

Why does it return such a small ranges?

Comment: and it's still the same for Samsung S10, Samsung S22 Ultra. No 60 fps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most camera devices cannot support high-speed operation with all the features still working.  For camera2, there's an explicit [constrained high speed mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) for 120/240 fps cases.

60fps is generally supported via normal mode, but it's always possible a manufacturer only exposes it in their custom camera app, usually due to performance or power constraints that make it difficult to support for all 3rd-party apps.

Comment: The strange thing is that `StreamConfigurationMap#getOutputMinFrameDuration` for, e.g., `1920x1080` gives me `16666666`, which if 60 FPS, but at the same time the maximal auto-exposure range is `30-30`. AFAIU, the only thing left is to set `CONTROL_AE_MODE` to `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF` and to manually control `SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION`, `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` and `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` to actually get 60 fps?

Comment: @Eddy - So if a device doesn't expose 60fps in CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES we might still be able to use 60fps?

Comment: @gioravered it's not what he said